# User picture and name is blank

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

App version: 1.0.25

- Log out of your account and click "Start using without an account"
- Open the left hand side menu
- Click "Feed"
- Next open the left hand side menu and go into a different stack site
- Then log in
- Open the left hand side menu
- The space that had the option to "Sign up or log in" is blank instead of showing the user picture and name.

If I click on the blank space it will bring me to my profile. I can fix this by logging out and then back in.

[image]

Comment: Seeing the `status-completed` for `android-app`, I thought a newer version is going to release for android-app. But sadly `status-completed` for old version. 

Comment: @Arulkumar yeah, it's quite common for old bugs that someone find out got silently fixed, then flagging the question asking for the tag to be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v1.0.83<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it has been fixed: Logging in will show username and profile picture correctly in place of Stack Exchange logo and "Sign up or log in" text.